# How to drawline between 2 markers in videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I want to draw line between 2 markers i,e between `'['` and `']'` boxes.

I have 2 points i,e `startTime` and `endTime` I get them by function `getRandomStartOrEndTime()`, i will consider **smaller** time as `startTime` and larger one as `endTime`

Two boxes `[` is `]` drawn by `markplayer()`.

**Here is what I have tried:**

```js
var player = videojs('example_video_1');

function getRandomStartOrEndTime(){
    var x = player.duration()// can be any number
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*x) + 1;
    return rand;
}


function markplayer(){
    player.markers.removeAll();
    var t1 = getRandomStartOrEndTime();
    var t2 = getRandomStartOrEndTime();
    var inTimeOutTimeList = [], index = 0;
    if(t1 < t2) {inTimeOutTimeList.push(t1);index = 1;
    }else{inTimeOutTimeList.push(t2);index = 0;}
    (index == 1) ? inTimeOutTimeList.push(t2) : inTimeOutTimeList.push(t1);
        for(var i = 0; i < inTimeOutTimeList.length; i++){
            player.markers.add([{
            time: inTimeOutTimeList[i],
            text: inTimeOutTimeList[i]
        }]);

        var icon = (i == 0) ? '[' : ']';
        $(".vjs-marker[data-marker-time='"+inTimeOutTimeList[i]+"']").html(icon);
    }
    // lineWidth = (inTimeOutTimeList[1] - inTimeOutTimeList[0])/player.duration()*100 + '%';
    // $('.vjs-marker').css('width',lineWidth);
};

player.markers({
//    markerTip:{
//       display: true,
//       text: function(marker) {
//          return "I am a marker tip: "+ marker.text;
//       }
//    },
   breakOverlay:{
      display: true,
      displayTime: 120,
      style:{
         'width':'100%',
         'height': '30%',
         'background-color': 'rgba(10,10,10,0.6)',
         'color': 'white',
         'font-size': '16px'
      }
   },
   markers: [
      {time:10, startTime:10, endTime:60, text: "this", overlayText: "1", class: "special-blue"},
   ]
});

intervalIntId = setInterval(function(){
    markplayer();
},3000);
```

```css
.vjs-fluid {
            overflow: hidden;
         }
         #example_video_1 .vjs-control-bar {
            display: block;
         }
         #example_video_1 .vjs-progress-control {
               bottom: 28px;
               left: 0;
               height: 10px;
               width: 100%;
         }
         
    .vjs-default-skin.vjs-has-started .vjs-control-bar {
            display: block !important;
            visibility: visible !important;
            opacity: 1 !important;
            /* bottom: -3.4em !important; */
            /* background-color: rgba(7, 20, 30, 1) !important; */
         }

.vjs-marker {
            background-color: transparent !important;
            height: 20px !important;
            font-size: 20px !important;
            color: red !important;
            font-weight: bold;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<video id="example_video_1" width="400" height="210" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{ "inactivityTimeout": 0 }'>
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: i have edited the question please check it out!!

Comment: You might want to look at this unfortunately abandonned range slider plugin: https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs It's using a very old version of Video.js so not really usable as-is but some of the code may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by calculating the difference between the two markers and assigning the difference as a width for a third marker.

Also note you are using an old version of video.js which is why the interface might look little different.

Here is an example:

```js
var player = videojs('example_video_1');

function getRandomStartOrEndTime() {
  var x = player.duration() // can be any number
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * x) + 1;
  return rand;
}


function markplayer() {
  player.markers.removeAll();
  var t1 = getRandomStartOrEndTime();
  var t2 = getRandomStartOrEndTime();
  var inTimeOutTimeList = [],
    index = 0;
  if (t1 < t2) {
    inTimeOutTimeList.push(t1);
    index = 1;
  } else {
    inTimeOutTimeList.push(t2);
    index = 0;
  }
  (index == 1) ? inTimeOutTimeList.push(t2): inTimeOutTimeList.push(t1);
  for (var i = 0; i < inTimeOutTimeList.length; i++) {
    player.markers.add([{
      time: inTimeOutTimeList[i],
      text: inTimeOutTimeList[i]
    }]);

    var icon = (i == 0) ? '[' : ']';
    $(".vjs-marker[data-marker-time='" + inTimeOutTimeList[i] + "']").html(icon);
  }
 
  player.markers.add([{
    time: inTimeOutTimeList[0],
    text: "I'm new",
    overlayText: "I'm new",
    class: 'range-marker'
  }]);

 //jQuery(".range-marker").width();
 const first = jQuery(".vjs-marker").eq(0).position().left;
 const last = jQuery(".vjs-marker").eq(1).position().left;
 
 const width = last - first;
 jQuery(".range-marker").width(width+"px");

  // lineWidth = (inTimeOutTimeList[1] - inTimeOutTimeList[0])/player.duration()*100 + '%';
  // $('.vjs-marker').css('width',lineWidth);
};

player.markers({
  //    markerTip:{
  //       display: true,
  //       text: function(marker) {
  //          return "I am a marker tip: "+ marker.text;
  //       }
  //    },
  breakOverlay: {
    display: true,
    displayTime: 120,
    style: {
      'width': '100%',
      'height': '30%',
      'background-color': 'rgba(10,10,10,0.6)',
      'color': 'white',
      'font-size': '16px'
    }
  },
  markers: [{
    time: 10,
    startTime: 10,
    endTime: 60,
    text: "this",
    overlayText: "1",
    class: "special-blue"
  }, ]
});

intervalIntId = setInterval(function() {
  markplayer();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.vjs-fluid {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example_video_1 .vjs-control-bar {
  display: block;
}

#example_video_1 .vjs-progress-control {
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-js .vjs-progress-control:hover .vjs-play-progress:after {
  display: none;
}

.vjs-marker {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: red !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.vjs-marker.range-marker
{
 background-color: orange !important;
 height: 3px !important;
 margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.6.5/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<video id="example_video_1" width="400" height="210" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```